# Java's multiline regex behavior

Tags: java, regex, multiline

In multiline mode, I expected Java

```
"BEGIN\n\n  END".replaceAll("(?m)^\\s+|\\s+$", "")
```

to result in

```
"BEGIN\n\nEND"
```

but instead it results in

```
"BEGINEND"
```

What am I missing please?

Comment: `\s` includes `\n`. You can use `[^\S\n]` instead of `\s`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`MULTILINE` doesn't change interpretation of `\n` as `\s` matches all whitespace characters including newline.

You can use `\h` (horizontal whitespace) instead of `\s` to make it work (available from Java 8 onwards):

```
String repl = "BEGIN\n\n  END".replaceAll("(?m)^\\h+|\\h+$", "");
```

---

If you are on older Java versions then use this instead of `\h`: (thanks to @ctwheels)

```
[^\S\n]
```

Comment: The character class `\h` is the shorthand equivalent of the posix character class `[:blank:]`. In Java, the blank character class can be specified as `\p{Blank}`. This is a more accurate replacement for older versions of Java.